# Adding squares to a map sized by their area

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I'm encountering a brick wall trying to add squares to my map.  I'm using the wonderful Leaflet.draw plugin, but it only supports Rectangles.  Each square has to be of the same area: 25miles^2.  I tried using icons but they don't resize on zoom, and I don't necessarily want to resort to disabling zooming. Furthermore, I noticed that while panning around my map, the scale was constantly adjusting. This leads me to believe that even at the same zoom level, a 20mile square will be shaped differently.

It seems like the only way to add shapes to the map is with Lat and Lng, so I know I have to come up with a way to convert LatLng to Area and vice-versa.

Looking for any feedback whatsoever! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate destination points with Turfjs destination method:

> Takes a Point and calculates the location of a destination point given a distance in degrees, radians, miles, or kilometers; and bearing in degrees. This uses the Haversine formula to account for global curvature.

http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_destination.html

With one given point you can derive the rest of the three points you need to create a new polygon:

```
var nw = {
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [lng, lat]
  }
};

// Go from northwest to northeast etc.
var ne = turf.destination(nw, 25, 90, 'miles'),
    se = turf.destination(ne, 25, 180, 'miles'),
    sw = turf.destination(se, 25, 270, 'miles');

// Nested array of coordinates. Note reversing of coordinates
// because GeoJSON uses [lng, lat]. Leaflet uses [lat, lng]
var coordinates = [
  nw.geometry.coordinates.reverse(),
  ne.geometry.coordinates.reverse(),
  se.geometry.coordinates.reverse(),
  sw.geometry.coordinates.reverse()
];

// Create a new polygon with coordinates
var polygon = new L.Polygon(coordinates).addTo(map);
```

Example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/C2iLJF?p=preview

Comment: This is incredible and exactly what I needed.  Thank you so very much!

Comment: No thanks, glad to help. I don't know what you're exactly trying to accomplish but this: http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_square-grid.html might come in handy too. Good luck with your project, cheers!